# Ember.js nested views get very slow

Tags: ember.js

I have a two-level deep data model that I want to display with Ember.js as nested lists. If I do the simple version it performs quite well:

```
    {{#each parent in content}}
    <p>Table {{parent.id}}</p>
          <ul>
              {{#each item in parent.children}}
                <ul>
                  <li>{{item.position}}</li>
                  <li>{{item.position}}</li>
                  <li>{{item.position}}</li>
                </ul>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
    {{/each}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/TdZJG/

However if instead of displaying the model's properties as raw strings I use nested Ember.Select and Ember.TextArea views the performance suffers a lot, it takes quite a bit after the load button is pressed to display the controls in the page:

```
    {{#each parent in content}}
            <ul>
              {{#each item in parent.children}}
                <ul>
                  <li>pos: {{item.position}}</li>
                  <li>
                    {{view Ember.Select
                        class="input-small"
                        contentBinding="App.CheckValues"
                        selectionBinding="item.status"}}
                  </li>
                  <li>{{view Ember.TextArea class="textarea-animated" name="description" valueBinding="item.comment"}}</li>
                </ul>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
    {{/each}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/wtwHN/

Would you have any suggestion on how to improve performance. This is done with ember-1.0.0-pre4

Comment: This is due to the bindings you are creating in your second approach. Creating Bindings is an expensive task.

Comment: I guess this could be mitigated by writing a ContainerView to minimize those Binding setups. But unfortunately i have not yet developed an own ContainerView.

Comment: I wonder if you can do the bindings at the higher level, that may help to reduce the amount of bindings.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be the way to go. Then you would habe something like this in your template: {{view App.YourContainerView contextBinding="item"}} and inside this container you may pass item.status and App.CheckValues manually. I once had a Binding inside a model that was created very often and this Binding was a major impact on performance.

Comment: I tried with a ContainerView and it seems a tad faster but it is still slow. At the end for Ember.Select you need 2 bindings anyway.

Comment: Here is my last jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/wtwHN/7/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Ember select and textarea views use normal html tags for them and bind only the attributes. Those views usually occupy more memory and writing them inside a nested structure will expectedly make your code run slow.